# Cannot fight at Gym

Tags: pokemon-go

I can pick up items in pokestop and catch pokemon. But when I approach the Gym, I can never use the Gym. It seems that the game will push me out of the range of the Gym. Can any one tell me why?

Comment: You need to be within range of the game. The game does not *simply push you out of range.*

Comment: Are you level 5 yet?

Comment: Your GPS position is too inaccurate. Check your device's GPS settings to a more accurate way.

Comment: Yes. I have reached lvl 5. I have setting my Gps as High accuracy. But this still happens. I am pretty sure that I stand right under the building which is Gym in the game, but in the game it shows 'This gym is too far away'

Comment: Try going to another gym if you can. It may be that the GPS signal is weak around that area.

Comment: @HazaiZhang "I am pretty sure that I stand right under the building which is Gym in the game" like do you mean you are standing in the spot what is the supposed to be the gym?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that occasionally GPS data will be terrible around one particular Gym, causing it to fail to load. I had this problem a lot during launch but it should be a lot better now. You can always try restarting your device as well just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Besides early server issues, the problem could be due to weak cellular signal.  With weak signal, your phone cannot reliably communicate with the server.  I have seen this occur with gyms, pokestops, and pokemon.

Answer (score 0):

Is your gym inside a big building? If it is, the GPS signal will likely be blocked. So your trainer location will be too inaccurate inside. If it is more serious, you can't even play.